Zsh script to filter array excluding a substring
I'm trying to create a filter that should exclude all items from an array except for those that match a pattern with a substring exclusion.
Given
myArr=(mySrv-dev-east-prj1 mySrv-dev-west-prj1 mySrv-qa-east-prj2 mySrv-qa-west-prj2 mySrv-uat-prd-east-prj3 mySrv-uat-prd-west-prj3 mySrv-prd-east-prj4 mySrv-prd-west-prj4)
if [[ ${myEnvSelection:l} == 'prod' ]] then
    setopt extended_glob
    needle_env="prd~uat"
else
    needle_env=${myEnvSelection:l}
fi
needle=*${needle_env:l}*${region:l}*  # *prd~uat*east*
filtered_result=(${(M)myArr:#$~needle})
unsetopt extended_glob

What happens is I get all uat-prd and prd items (4) when I setopt extended_glob. But without that set, I get no items returned. If I set needle=*prd*east* I will get the east versions for both uat-prd and prd.  I've also tried needle=*prd*east*~uat and it gives m 2 items returned (uat-prd-east and prd-east).
I know I'm misunderstanding how to do the pattern, but I'm not sure what I should try next.

Putting the match and exclude filters into a parenthesized group appears to work:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# arg1, environment: dev qa uat-prd prd
# arg2, region: east west *
filterServerArray() {
    # with localoptions, extendedglob will
    # only apply to this function
    setopt extendedglob localoptions
    local envFilter=${${1:?}:l}
    if [[ $envFilter == prd ]]; then
        envFilter+='~*uat-prd'
    fi
    local region=${${2:?}:l}
    local filter="(*$envFilter)*$region*"
    print "filter: $filter"
    filteredResult=(${(M)myArr:#$~filter})
    print 'result:' $filteredResult
}
myArr=( mySrv-dev-east-prj1     mySrv-dev-west-prj1
        mySrv-qa-east-prj2      mySrv-qa-west-prj2
        mySrv-uat-prd-east-prj3 mySrv-uat-prd-west-prj3
        mySrv-prd-east-prj4     mySrv-prd-west-prj4
)
filterServerArray dev east
## filter: (*dev)*east*
## result: mySrv-dev-east-prj1

filterServerArray dev '*'
## filter: (*dev)***
## result: mySrv-dev-east-prj1 mySrv-dev-west-prj1

filterServerArray prd east
## filter: (*prd~*uat-prd)*east*
## result: mySrv-prd-east-prj4

The patterns like (*prd~*uat-prd)*east* include the initial wildcard in the parenthesized group. This is important - the * will always be 'greedy', and 'consume' the letters prior to prd. So the negative comparison with uat uses the * to rewind to include the prior characters.
Similarly, the exclusion pattern can be applied to an entire string, e.g. with *prd*east*~*uat*. But this pattern is dangerously broad; a string like mySrv-prd-east-uatproj would also be filtered from the array, even though that probably wasn't the intent.


prd~uat matches any string that is prd and is not uat. So that's the same as prd alone.
*prd~uat*east* matches any string that ends in prd and that does not start with uat followed by something that contains east
*prd*east*~uat matches anything that contains prd and east in that order and is not uat. Of course, anything that contains prd and east cannot be uat, so that's the same as *prd*east*.

If you want something that ends in prd but does not contain uat which is then followed by something that contains east, that would be (*prd~*uat*)*east* or (^*uat*)prd*east*.
From your sample, it looks like those uat/east/prd  are --delimited and -uat precedes -prd and -east- follows prd. To avoid the uat matching in a Guatemala server name, and east matching in beast, you could be more explicit and do (^*-uat)-prd-east-* which matches any thing that doesn't end in -uat followed by -prd-east- followed by anything (even containing -uat-).
